# How do I write this symbol in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I just registered to ask how do I write this symbol, because it's what holds me away from continuing the programming. The tutorial I was looking at is being narrated in some language I do not know, so maybe you do know!

Here is the picture;
http://prntscr.com/9iitiy - Thanks!

Comment: did you try shift+f7?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I just couldn't understand what exactly it was as it was quite distorted, plus I just started learning Android Development today!

Answer (score 0):

This symbol **&** is an *ampersand*. The thing you highlighted is just two of them.

It is on the 7 key on the keyboard. `shift + 7`

Comment: I just facepalmed hard, the low quality video made it distorted and so did the Android Studio itself, thanks a lot!